# How to upload a file using an ajax call in flask

Tags: python, ajax, flask

Hi I'm quite new to flask and I want to upload a file using an ajax call to the server. As mentioned in the documentation, I added a file upload to the html as folows:

```
<form action="" method=post enctype="multipart/form-data" id="testid">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
     <label>Upload</label>
   </td>
   <td>
     <input id="upload_content_id" type="file" name="upload_file" multiple>
     <input type="button" name="btn_uplpad" id="btn_upload_id" class="btn-upload" value="Upload"/>

   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

and I wrote the ajax handler as this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn_upload_id" ).click(function() {           
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/uploadajax",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success : function (data) {},
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
        });
    });
});
```

I do not know how to get the uploaded file (not the name) from this

```
  <input id="upload_content_id" type="file" name="upload_file" multiple>
```

and save the file in folder. I'm not quite sure how to read the file from handler which i have written:

```
@app.route('/uploadajax', methods = ['POST'])
def upldfile():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_val = request.files['file']
```

I will be grateful if anyone can help. Thank you in advance

Comment: You can have a look at this post which suggests a flask-sijax to handle that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416706/upload-file-in-ajax-with-wtforms

Answer (score 68, accepted):

To answer your question...

HTML:

```
<form id="upload-file" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="file">Select a file</label>
        <input name="file" type="file">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <button id="upload-file-btn" type="button">Upload</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#upload-file-btn').click(function() {
        var form_data = new FormData($('#upload-file')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/uploadajax',
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('Success!');
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Now in your flask's endpoint view function, you can access the file's data via flask.request.files.

On a side note, forms are not tabular data, therefore they do not belong in a table. Instead, you should resort to an unordered list, or a definition list.

Comment: Can you explain the code: new FormData($('#upload-file')[0]); What does the "0" means?

Comment: Use Firebug, or whichever developer tools you use to bring up you browser's console. Now, in your JavaScript file: console.log($("#upload-file")); - As you can see, it returns an object. Suffixing with "[0]" selects the first item in the object. FormData(<first item in object>) creates a new FormData object, which is the object needed to send to your server.

Comment: I confirm that this should be the accepted answer. Works like charm! :) Thanks @onosendi!

Comment: As for your side note: unfortunatelly, given CSS current state (*), it is still an order of magnitude easier to have the input fields aligned one to another with a table than using other techniques. (*) It simply seens to be a missing use case on the CSS2 and 3 specs - -either that, or tables are indeed expected.

Comment: @onosendi tried to use your answer with some AJAX, do U know what I'm doing wrong here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995516/getting-an-empty-immutablemultidict-object-from-jquery-request-data Thank you in advance!

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form is very important!

Comment: I get a deprecation warning when running this on Chrome: `XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/`. Changing `async` to `true` fixes it.

Comment: @GustavoBezerra
You can remove async:false in order to get rid of that error. See 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736186/jquery-has-deprecated-synchronous-xmlhttprequest

Comment: Removed `async: false` from my answer.

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript (client side):

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', $('#uploadfile').prop('files')[0]);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/uploadLabel',
    data: form_data,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Success!');
    },
});
```

Python (server side):

```
@app.route('/uploadLabel', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def uploadLabel():
    isthisFile = request.files.get('file')
    print(isthisFile)
    print(isthisFile.filename)
    isthisFile.save('./' + isthisFile.filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a problem where the saved file was being empty, it turned out to be because of the pointer. Since I could not find anyone that mentioned this, here is a suggestion:

Files in a FormData request can be accessed at `request.files` then you can select the file you included in the FormData e.g. `request.files['audio']`.

So now if you want to access the actual bytes of the file, in our case 'audio' using `.stream`, you should make sure first that your cursor points to the first byte and not to the end of the file, in which case you will get empty bytes.

Hence, a good way to do it:

```
file = request.files['audio']
file.stream.seek(0)
audio = file.read()
```