# How to upload files and other data in the same request asynchronously using AJAX to a Flask server?

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

The solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20107080/3664835) helps in uploading files asynchronously.

When I change it to include both the files and some string data I'm unable to access both the string and the files.

This is what I have so far:

```
<body>
  <h4>Select files to be uploaded</h4>
  <br/>
  <form id="upload-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><input type="file" multiple="" name="files" id="files"></p>
    <p><input type="button" class="btn" id="upload-file-btn" value="Upload" /></p>
  </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      $('#upload-file-btn').click(function() {
          var form_data = new FormData($('#upload-form')[0])
          console.log(form_data)
          console.log('Starting upload')
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '/upload',
              data: { form_data: form_data,
                      path: 'test_folder_2/'
                    },
              contentType: false,
              cache: false,
              processData: false,
              async: false,
              success: function(data) {
                console.log('Success')
              },
              error: function() {
                console.log('Error')
              }
          });
      });
  });
</script>
```

This is my view on the server:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    path = request.form.get('path')
    print("PATH: ", path)
    path = path or 'test_folder_2/' # Fallback
    if request.method == 'POST':
        files = request.files.getlist('files')
        print("FILES: ", files)
        filenames = [_ for _ in os.listdir(os.path.join('.', 'content', path ))]
        for file in files:
            if file and helpers.is_allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = helpers.get_name(file.filename, filenames)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], path, filename))
    return 'Done'
```

The output of this is:
PATH: None
FILES: []

I tried JSON.stringify() to send the data, but the files don't seem to be arriving to the server on doing that.

FWIW this is what I'm trying to do: Receive a bunch of files from the client and store it in the file specified by the "path".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you could deal with the issue:

1. Simply `append` the extra key and value:

   ```
   form_data.append("path", "test_folder_2/")
   ```

   and then send the data on its way:

   ```
   data: form_data
   ```
2. Add a hidden field to the form with the path and `FormData` will do that for you:

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="path" value="test_folder_2/">
   ```

Comment: This can be accessed in the view as `path = request.form.get("path")`