# Flask AJAX request returns empty ImmutableMultiDict, same AJAX works with http.server

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I am transitioning from http.server to Flask. My image upload using AJAX is now broken. This is running Python 3.

**Troubleshooting that  did not work:**

- I have included multipart/form-data in the Ajax request.
- I have tried to have a shared and dedicated route for the upload.
- I have added @cross_origin() it solved the problem for a similar question.
- I tried looking in other request dicts, nothing contains anything.
- I originally ran the app on 0.0.0.0, so changed that to 127.0.0.1.
- I tried to add an entire form to the FormData and just the image. I am reluctant to change much more of the Ajax since it works on http.server.
- Tried both sync and async AJAX requests.

No matter what I attempt I always get the same result:

`print(request.files)` returns `ImmutableMultiDict([])`

I'ld rather avoid using JQuery, as this *should* work since it works on http.server.

**Relevant code:**

Non-working Flask:

```py
@app.route("/qr_upload", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@cross_origin()
def receive_image():
  if (request.method == "POST"):
    print("qr_code" in request.files)  # This always returns False.
    multipart_data = request.files["qr_code"]

  return "Post"


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run("127.0.0.1", PORT, True)
```

Working AJAX on http.server

```
    // Add the image to the request and send it.
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("qrPickerForm"))

    xhttp.open("POST", "/qr_upload")
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
    xhttp.send(formData)
```

Related HTML

```html
<form action = "/qr_upload" id = "qrPickerForm" name = "qr_form" method="post" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    <input id = "qrFilePicker" name = "qr_code" type = "file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Working http.server:

```py
 def do_POST(self):
    # Extract the multiform data from the POST request
    cLen = int(self.headers["Content-Length"])
    body = self.rfile.read(cLen)

    # Decode the multiform data and get the image bytes.
    multipart_data = decoder.MultipartDecoder(body, "multipart/form-data; boundary=WebKitFormBoundary")

    # This and Flask's code should have the same data here.

Handler = S
with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT-1), Handler) as httpd:
  httpd.serve_forever()
```

**Update 1:**

It works if I send the image with a form's submit button, but not with AJAX. Have not figured out why yet though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting an empty ImmutableMultiDict object from jQuery request data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995516/getting-an-empty-immutablemultidict-object-from-jquery-request-data)

Comment: @KateOrlova I'm not running JQuery though?

Comment: Ok, @Fivreld. Does your form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute? I hope it does otherwise **files** will be empty.

Comment: @KateOrlova Shouldn't this `xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")` be enough?

Comment: No, it is not. That should be specified for your `<form>` tag in HTML view, please check your form definition.

Comment: @KateOrlova I've found a solution. See my dedicated answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

I dug around a little bit in Wireshark since it seemed weird to me that it worked on one HTTP server but not another.

This is the Content-Type of the request to http.server and when using the submit button:
`Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryLiIs2nrWOjrabtB1`

This is the Content-Type of the broken request: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`

So it seems like setting a Content-Type directly with `xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")`was a bad idea, presumably as it overwrites the enctype set in the , but without the boundary.

I removed the line and it now works as intended.

Comment: Very good, @Fivreld, I am glad that you have found the solution!

Comment: Thanks. I was having the same problem with jQuery. `$.ajax({ contentType: 'multipart/form-data' })` errors, while `$.ajax({ contentType: false })` works.