# Flask uploading files to flask without form

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-3.x, flask

I want to be able to upload my file from javascript without using the typical HTML form so that the page doesn't have to refresh when uploading the file to python.

I have not had any success getting my file with `request.files`.
I have tried two different versions, one using an HTML form and one without.

When trying out the one with the HTML form, the output from `request.files` is an ImmutableMultiDict that looks like this `ImmutableMultiDict([('file', <FileStorage: '^RUT.csv' ('text/csv')>)])` whilst according to my understanding, it is supposed to be a dictionary. 
Here is the code:

```
<form method="POST" action="/get_dims" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="import_form">
                <input type="file" name="file" accept=".csv" id="training_set_import" value="import training set"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

```py
@app.route("/get_dims", methods=["POST"])
def getDatasetDims():
    file_n = request.files
    print("Got it!")
    print(file_n)
    return "None"
```

The other, preferable method I have tried is with javascript using AJAX. When doing this, `request.files` returns an empty ImmutableMultiDict that looks like this `ImmutableMultiDict([])`. Here is my code for this:

```js
$(function(){
    $("#training_set_import").change(function(){
      var file_name = $("#training_set_import").val();
      var form = $("#training_set_import").form;
      var data = new FormData(form);
      if (file_name !== ""){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url:"/get_dims",
          enctype: "multipart/form-data",
          data: {"file": data},
          cache: false,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false
        });
      }
    });
});
```

The python code is the same.

So my question is, how can I implement the javascript version of this so that I can manupulate the uploaded csv in python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found a thread on here that solved my issues. Here it is: [How to upload a file using an ajax call in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334717/how-to-upload-a-file-using-an-ajax-call-in-flask)
Hope this helps anyone with the same issue as me !